# Flask-SqlAlchemy query with order_by and pagination is very slow

Tags: postgresql, flask, pagination, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by

I use **Python**=2.7.3, **PostgreSQL**=9.3, **Flask**=0.10.0, **SQLAlchemy**=1.10.12, **Flask-SQLAlchemy**=2.1 and **psycopg2**=2.5.4

I have a 1 billion records table in PostgreSQL, and I have to paginate over it and provide search in it:

```
class MyTable(db.Model):
    """ My Table """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.String(100), index=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(512), index=True)
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
```

So i did the following in the code where i request data:

```
records = MyTable.query.filter(**filter_list).\
    order_by(asc('code')).paginate(page, per_page, False)
```

The point is it takes like 13 seconds to just select 10 last records for the last page if per_page=10 and page=1158960 **even when there's no filtering at all**.

From what i found in flask-sqlalchemy source, **.paginate** does it like this:

```
.order_by(asc('code')).limit(per_page).offset((page - 1) * per_page)
```

The resulting SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT my_table.id, my_table.code, my_table.name 
FROM my_table ORDER BY my_table.code ASC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1158960
```

When i fired it on a server console, i realized that the problem is in **ORDER BY** clause. Somehow it has to first sort the whole table with **ORDER BY** and only then **LIMIT** and **OFFSET**. But that's slow as hell.

**EXPLAIN (ANALYZE):**

```
"Limit  (cost=470520.26..470520.26 rows=1 width=178) (actual time=12460.060..12460.061 rows=8 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=467626.96..470520.26 rows=1157320 width=178) (actual time=11343.220..12424.686 rows=1158968 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: code"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 218312kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..42518.20 rows=1157320 width=178) (actual time=0.026..378.637 rows=1158968 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 12475.160 ms"
```

If you just remove **ORDER BY** from that SQL request, it completes in 270ms!

```
"Limit  (cost=42518.20..42518.20 rows=1 width=178) (actual time=269.940..269.942 rows=8 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..42518.20 rows=1157320 width=178) (actual time=0.030..246.200 rows=1158968 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 269.992 ms"
```

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: What indices do you have on the table? What filters are you trying to apply?

Comment: `Seq Scan on my_table` probably means that index `ix_my_table_code` is not being used for `ORDER BY` operation. I would test `reindex index ix_my_table_code` to see if `Index Scan using ix_my_table_code on my_table` appears in `explain analyze ...`

Comment: @univerio About indexes, they're default indexes created by flask-sqlalchemy: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_my_table_code ON my_table USING btree (code COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

Comment: @J.J.Hakala I did the reindex as you suggested but nothing changed. Also I don't really understand - if an index is built for a field with default ASC order - why does ORDER_BY ... ASC for that field forces Sort operation that we see in EXPLAIN? Aren't the records already sorted in that index?

Comment: @Tosh I did my testing with postgresql 9.4 and I don't know if it behaves differently that version 9.3 in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to solve that.

When i do exactly the same query but with **SET enable_seqscan=off;** it forces PostgreSQL to use **Index Scan** instead of Sequence Scan, and it gets **much faster**!

```
SET enable_seqscan=off;
SELECT my_table.id, my_table.code, my_table.name 
FROM my_table ORDER BY my_table.code ASC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1158960

**EXPLAIN (ANALYZE):**

"Limit  (cost=1814764.86..1814777.39 rows=8 width=131) (actual time=616.543..616.545 rows=8 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using ix_my_table_code on my_table  (cost=0.43..1814777.39 rows=1158968 width=131) (actual time=0.065..590.898 rows=1158968 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 616.568 ms"
```

So now the point is - how do I set PostgreSQL config to make it use Index Scan without forcing it? I guess the answer is - "**Planner Cost Constants**". Any advices about them?

**UPDATE 13.04.2016:**

I finally figured out the situation and found a solution. In my case, everything is solved by setting **Planner Cost Constants** like this in **postgresql.conf**:

```
seq_page_cost = 1.0
random_page_cost = 1.0
cpu_tuple_cost = 0.01
cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.0001
cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025
effective_cache_size = 1024MB
```

Also, there're many advises to set effective_cache_size as 3/4 from a server entire RAM. Anyway, with these settings Planner always uses Index Scan on Huge tables. So timing is now 200-300ms.

**Problem Solved.**

Comment: Didn't notice that `OFFSET` before. That's a ridiculous offset. I think that may be why. Try removing the offset? If that's the reason, my advice is to page using `WHERE code > [some code] ORDER BY code` instead of `OFFSET [n] LIMIT [m]`.

Comment: @univerio but I need that OFFSET to move from page to page at the frontend, knowing elements amount per page. The code isn't an increment column, so If i want to show page #12000 to the user, knowing per_page, how exactly do u suggest getting the last element code before that page, so i could use it in **WHERE** clause? And also - using Index Scan it works quite well, so the point now is - how to either set that enable_seqscan=off from SQLAlchemy ORM request, or change postgres planner settings to make it work?

Comment: You can't page like that when you have a huge table. What if the user wants page 100,000,000 (OFFSET 1 billion)? You'll run into the exact same problem. The only way to solve this is to only let the user page forwards and backwards n pages (simplest case is n = 1) and use `WHERE` instead of `OFFSET`.

Comment: @univerio Agreed. That's exactly how i'm doing it right now. User can move to either next page, or previous, if they exist. But also user should have buttons to move to first or last page. And what records they contain depends much on **ORDER BY**, which is defined by a user choice of sorting field and ASC/DESC. Anyways, I dove into **Planner Cost Constants** docs, and tuned them to make Index Scan work without forcing **SET enable_seqscan=off;**

Comment: @Tosh Could you kindly tell how to solve this in MySQL?